# Question about thread safetty. Is it thread safe?

Tags: java, thread-safety

wondering if this way to use jdbc resources in Java is thread safe. Is there  a better way to do this? This is a very small application the requirement is not to use off the shelf stuff like hibernate etc.

```
class DBHelper {
    private static String dbHost;
    private static String dbPort;
    ...

    private static boolean getSettings() {
        //Initialize variables above from mongodb
        DB_HOST = dao.getHost();
        DB_PORT = dao.getPort();
        //return true if variables not empty
    }

    public static String callProcedures() {
       //NOTE taking care of cleaning up resources etc, 
       // in try catch finally not adding here.
       if (getConfigurations) {
            // Variables init success
            String dbURL = "jdbc:oracle:thin....;
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection()..;
            String res1 = callProc1(conn);
            String res2 = callProc2(conn);
            conn.close();
            return res1+res2;
       }
    }

    private static String callProc1(Connection conn, ) {
         CallableStatement stmt = conn.prepareCall("...");
         stmt.setString("CL_1","val");
         stmt.execute();
         return stmt.getInt(RES); 
    }

    private static String callProc2(Connection conn, ) {
         CallableStatement stmt = conn.prepareCall("...");
         stmt.setString("CL_1","val");
         stmt.execute();
         return stmt.getInt(RES); 
    }

}
```

The DBHelper is used in SPARK post call

```
post(API_CONTEXT + "/url", "application/json", (request, response) -> {
      String res = DBHelper.callProcedures();
      return res...;
}, new JsonTransformer());
```

Comment: All your methods are private. It is not clear how can they be called, or if they called at all. Show your full code.

Comment: Assuming there is some way to call it, it's probably not thread-safe. You're overwriting the static variables. (Btw, those aren't constants, so don't write them in `CONSTANT_CASE`). (And why have two variables to hold, presumably, the same value?)

Comment: Apologies fixed the code. Will making them final and initializing  them in static initializer make it thread safe?